# NiFi How to avoid hitting redis for each flow file

Tags: caching, redis, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow like below,

[image: nifi]

In my case each flowfile after consumer getting hit to redis, is there a way where I can avoid each hit.

I want to hit after local TTL expires , like read data from redis and store in  local cache and  then read after some TTL.

Comment: What NiFi processor are you using to communicate with Redis? There is no ConsumeRedis processor

Comment: my consumer is not redis, it is kafka consumer it read data and send next processor, RedisDistributedMapCacheClientService I am using this processor

Comment: Ok Redis DMC is controller service, not a processor, so your flow is ConsumeKafka -> FetchDistributedMapCache which is configured with Redis DMC... there is no local cache, the whole point of using Redis is for it to be the cache itself